# Ajax file upload in .Net 6 Razor pages sends Null in the codebehind

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-ajax, .net-6.0, razor-pages

Already tried [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557434/net-core-6-razor-ajax-file-upload-not-mvc) but it did not work. So seeking help.

I have a .Net 6 Razor page from where I am trying to upload a file.

Here is my **AjaxFileUpload.CSHtml**

```
<h3>Ajax File Upload</h3>

 <form method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Select File 1</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile1">
      <br/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="UploadFile1ViaAjax()">Upload File 1</button>
      <span id="File1UploadStatus"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**The Ajax Call**

```
<script>
            
function UploadFile1ViaAjax()
{          
   var file1 = $('#formFile1').prop("files")[0];
   
   var url = "/Employees/AjaxFileUpload?handler=UploadFile1";
   formData = new FormData();
   formData.append(file1.name, file1);

   alert("Uploading file 1 : " + file1.name);

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,            
        data: formData, 
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken:
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        failure: function (result) {
            alert("failure");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        },
        }).done(function (result) {
                alert("ajax call complete.");
    });       
    
}   

</script>
```

Finally here is the code behind method **AjaxFileUpload.CSHtml.cs**

```
    public IActionResult OnPostUploadFile1(IFormFile formData)
    {
        if (formData != null)
        {               
            return new ObjectResult(new { status = "success" });
        }
        return new ObjectResult(new { status = "fail" });
    }
```

When I upload a file and click the button, The ajax call works and debugger is hit in the code behind method, but the problem is, the `IFormFile` object is always coming as null.

Why is this happening? How can I get the `IFormFile` object populated with file data that I am uploading ?

Comment: The problem is because the name of the parameter inside your C# endpoint doesn't match the ajax call. Try setting the `formdata.append("fileName", file)` and call the parameter in your endpoint fileName too. Other wise you should upload it either through submitting a form. Or uploading the file as base64

Comment: You are a lifesaver! it works! please post this as an answer so that I can mark it accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the name of the parameter inside your C# endpoint doesn't match the ajax call. Try setting the `formdata.append("fileName", file)` and call the parameter in your endpoint fileName too. Other wise you should upload it either through submitting a form. Or uploading the file as base64